# The derivative of the Cholesky factor

Tags: linear-algebra, matrix-analysis

Let $A$ be a symmetric, positive definite $p\times p$ matrix, and let $f(A)$ be its Cholesky factor. That is, $f(A)$ is a lower triangular $p\times p$ matrix such that $A = f(A) f(A)^{\top}$. I am wondering if the derivative
$$
\frac{\mathrm{d}\operatorname{vech}\left(f(A)\right)}{\mathrm{d}\operatorname{vech}\left(A\right)}
$$
is known, where $\operatorname{vech}$ is the half-vectorization function.

(I am conjecturing that it is something like $L^{\top} \left(f(A)\otimes A^{-1}\right) L$, where $L$ is the elimination matrix, but I would need a reference or proof anyway.)

Comment: Smith's paper (http://www.jstor.org/stable/1390762) makes me suspect there is no known closed form...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The derivative can be found via implicit differentiation. That is, 
$$
\frac{\mathrm{d}\operatorname{vec}\left(Y\right)}{\mathrm{d}\operatorname{vec}\left(X\right)} = \left(\frac{\mathrm{d} \operatorname{vec}\left(X\right)}{\mathrm{d}\operatorname{vec}\left(Y\right)}\right)^{-1}.$$
It is relatively easy to compute the derivative of $A$ with respect to $f(A)$ since $A = f(A)f(A)^{\top}$. The only trick part is restricting $f(A)$ to be lower triangular.

For general $X$, we have
$$
\frac{\mathrm{d} \operatorname{vec}\left(XX^{\top}\right)}{\mathrm{d} \operatorname{vec}\left(X\right)} = \left(I + K\right)\left(X\otimes I\right),$$
where $K$ is the [Commutation Matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Commutation_matrix).

Now to get the derivative with respect to the $\operatorname{vech}$ requires use of the chain rule. This gives
$$
\frac{\mathrm{d} \operatorname{vech}\left(XX^{\top}\right)}{\mathrm{d} \operatorname{vech}_{\Delta}\left(X\right)} = L \left(I + K\right)\left(X\otimes I\right) D,$$
where here $L$ is the elimination matrix, and $D$ is the "lower triangular duplication matrix" which has the property that $D \operatorname{vech}\left(M\right) = \operatorname{vec}\left(M\right)$ for lower triangular matrices $M$. The sought derivative is the matrix inverse of the above expression.

### numerical confirmation:

Here is a numerical confirmation in R: (note that the `chol` function in R is an operator from upper triangular matrices to upper triangular matrices, thus some mucking about with transposes):

```
require(matrixcalc)
set.seed(2349024)
n <- 6
X <- cov(matrix(rnorm(1000*n),ncol=n))
fnc <- function(X) t(chol(X))

Y <- fnc(X)
d0 <- (diag(1,nrow=n^2) + commutation.matrix(r=n)) %*% (Y %x% diag(1,nrow=n))
L <- elimination.matrix(n)
d1 <- L %*% d0 %*% t(L)
dfin <- solve(d1)

# now compute the approximate derivative
apx.d <- matrix(rep(NA,length(dfin)),nrow=dim(dfin)[1])
my.eps <- 1e-6
low.idx <- which(lower.tri(diag(1,n),diag=TRUE))
for (iii in c(1:length(low.idx))) {
    Xalt <- X
    tweak <- low.idx[iii]
    Xalt[tweak] <- Xalt[tweak] + my.eps
    # "Note that only the upper triangular part of 'x' is used..."
    Yalt <- fnc(t(Xalt))
    dY <- (Yalt - Y) / my.eps
    apx.d[,iii] <- dY[low.idx]
}
apx.error <- apx.d - dfin
max(abs(apx.error))
apx.error
```

The maximum absolute error I get is `5.606e-07`, on the order of the delta in the input variable, `1e-06`.

Comment: I am lead to believe there is a form of this in a paper by Fujikoshi and Okamoto in _J. Japan. Stat. Soc._, but I can find no more than the TOC for this journal: http://www.jss.gr.jp/ja/journal/jjss1976.html .

Comment: I think the paper is [here](https://www.jstage.jst.go.jp/article/jjss1970/6/2/6_2_33/_pdf), but it appears to talk about the eigendecomposition, not the Cholesky.

Comment: good find, @pete ! I believe you are right, but wonder if the F&O derivative could be somehow used for Cholesky decomposition--perhaps by considering the matrix 'square root' function.

Comment: I prefer your result, it's a little more direct. I wonder if you should change $D$ to $L^{\top}$ though, it took me a bit of thinking before I realised that $D$ isn't the full duplication matrix.

Comment: I suspect you are right, but have to convince myself again that $L^{\top}$ is the 'half' duplication matrix...

Comment: Columns of $L$ are either basis vectors or zero vectors. The submatrix of $L^{\top}L$ corresponding to non-zero elements of $M$ is the identity and the rest is zeros.

Comment: Theorem A.1 of [Simo Särkkä's _Bayesian Filtering and Smoothing_](http://www.cambridge.org/nz/academic/subjects/statistics-probability/applied-probability-and-stochastic-networks/bayesian-filtering-and-smoothing) gives a result for the scalar derivative $\frac{\partial A}{\partial\theta} = A\Phi\left(A^{-1}\frac{\partial P}{\partial\theta}{}A^{-\top}\right)$, where $P=AA^{\top}$, and $\Phi_{ij}(M) = M_{ij}$ where $i > j$; $\tfrac12M_{ij}$ where $i=j$; and $0$ where $i < j$. Using this I get the same thing as using your result above.

Comment: I can generalise that result to give me $\frac{d\operatorname{vech}A}{d\operatorname{vech}P} = L(I\otimes A)Q(A^{-1}\otimes A^{-1})D$, where $Q$ is the diagonal matrix that gives us $Q\operatorname{vec}M = \operatorname{vec}(\Phi(M))$, and $D$ is the usual duplication matrix for symmetric matrices. This is more direct, and inverts $A$ rather than the larger matrix, but needs us to introduce the function $\Phi$ and matrix $Q$.

Comment: For a lower triangular matrix $A$, $\operatorname{vec}A = L^\top\operatorname{vech}A$. Ref: [The Elimination Matrix: Some Lemmas and Applications](http://epubs.siam.org/doi/abs/10.1137/0601049).

Comment: Using that same paper, we can write $Q=\frac12(DL)^\top DL$ since $D^\top D = (L(I+K)L^\top)^{-1}$.

Comment: Hi, I was just wondering if anyone could clarify, what does the notation $\text{vech}_{\Delta}\left(X\right)$ mean above? Is this the vech of the cholesky factor?

Comment: I think intended it to mean the derivative with respect to the vech of $X$, but there is an oddity here in that $X$ need not be symmetric.

Comment: @pete what happens when I want to take the derivative of $A^T$? when I'm using [this](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1602.07527.pdf) paper, the perturbation becomes $dL^T = (dL)^T = (L \Phi(L^{-1}dA L^{-T}))^T = \Phi(L^{-1}dA L^{-T})^T L^T$, is that correct?

Comment: @pete and when using the chain differentiation with $A = f(\theta)$, the derivative, $\frac{\partial L}{\partial \theta} = L \Phi(L^{-1}\frac{\partial A}{\partial \theta} L^{-T})$, and not following the chain-rule: $\frac{\partial L}{\partial \theta} = \frac{\partial L}{\partial A} \cdot \frac{\partial A}{\partial \theta}$?

Comment: Hi @Dorian, it's been a while since I've looked at this but unless I've missed something $dL^T = (dL)^T$ as you suggest. Note that $\frac{\partial L}{\partial A}$ is a fourth-order tensor (and not a particularly nice one) which I think is why the chain rule isn't used directly here.

Comment: @pete thanks a lot, yes I used that and compared to the numerical derivative and it worked fine! however, I have a bit more advanced question that I posted [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3790709/derivative-of-matrix-vector-product), would you mind having a look at that as well? (I odn't want to extend that comment thread even more..)

Comment: @stollenm I don't think so? The first $DL$ is transposed.

Comment: @pete If $D$ is the duplication matrix and $L$ is an elimination matrix (which is not unique, see https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4081768/185047) then we can just take the Moore-Penrose inverse of $D$ as $L$, $L=(DD')^{-1}D'$, in which case it should work as I said.

Comment: @stollenm It "should" work? Have you tried it? Does it give the same answer for $\frac{d\operatorname{vech}A}{d\operatorname{vech}P}$?

Comment: @stollenm I take that to mean no, you haven't checked. Get back to me when you have.

Comment: @pete In fact you can write $Q = \frac{1}{2} (DL)^\top$ using Lemma 4.4 in http://epubs.siam.org/doi/abs/10.1137/0601049.

Comment: @stollenm That sounds a little more promising. Let me know when you've tested it and I'll have a look.

Comment: @pete man are you difficult to convince :) . It does check out numerically as well, obviously.

Comment: For those interested in a more citeable resource. The result in this answer has been derived in Lemma 1 of https://doi.org/10.1016/0304-4076(89)90059-6.

Comment: @stollem Well obviously I'm a lot easier to convince when the result is correct ;)
Did you find the mistake in your earlier attempts?

Comment: @pete The previous attempt yielded the same result.

Comment: I am a bit late in the comment, but I try. I am working in a similar setting, and if I understood correctly the Jacobian involving the vectorizations, since it has $I+K$ in it, is not invertible. On the other hand, the one with the half-vectorization is invertible. Can I recover the Jacobian of the vectorization in terms of the one with the half-vectorization?

Answer (score 8):

I've written a relevant note on arXiv: http://arxiv.org/abs/1602.07527

I included the neat closed form solution pete gives in a comment, and also a messy expression (converted to the notation f = chol(A)):
$$
    \frac{\partial f_{ij}}{\partial A_{kl}} =
    \bigg(\sum_{m>j} f_{im}f_{mk}^{-1} + \tfrac{1}{2}f_{ij}f_{jk}^{-1}\bigg)f_{jl}^{-1}
    +
    (1-\delta_{kl})\bigg(\sum_{m>j} f_{im}f_{ml}^{-1} + \tfrac{1}{2}f_{ij}f_{jl}^{-1}\bigg)f_{jk}^{-1}.
$$

However, if you're interested in differentiating a larger expression, you can do that in $O(N^3)$, without computing all $O(N^4)$ derivatives in $\frac{\partial \mathrm{vech}(f)}{\partial \mathrm{vech}A}$. The note explains different ways to do that.

(pete: if you tell me who you are, I'll add a proper acknowledgement to my note in any future revision.)

Comment: FWIW, I have implemented the derivative in the `madness` R package: https://github.com/shabbychef/madness/blob/master/R/matwise.r#L76-L88

Comment: Thanks. I've made a note to add a link in my next revision.

Comment: Thanks! There is a simple C++ implementation of the above [here](https://gist.github.com/boennecd/db151d693435c0bdbcec96f61e380014) if anyone finds it useful.

Comment: Quick question: What is $\delta_{kl}$ here?

Comment: It must be the Kronecker delta: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kronecker_delta

Comment: Yes, $\delta_{kl}$ is a Kronecker delta.

Answer (score 1):

The following may be of help. If $A=T'T$ (where $T$ is upper triangular), then you can show that (see. Thm. 2.1.9 in *Aspects of Multivariate Statistical Theory* by R. J. Muirhead):
\begin{equation*}
 (dA) = 2^p\prod_{i=1}^p t_{ii}^{p+1-i}(dT),
\end{equation*}
where using exterior products, we define $(dA) := \bigwedge_{i \le j}^p da_{ij}$; similarly, $(dT)=\bigwedge_{i\le j}^p dt_{ij}$.

*Note:* You are essentially asking for $dA$ not $(dA)$ --- if all elements of $A$ are distinct, then of course both coincide, otherwise not.

Answer (score 1):

Let $T=\{M|M \text{ lower triangular }\},T^+=\{M\in T|\;m_{i,i}>0 \},S^+=\{M|M \text{ SPD }\}$ and $\phi:C=[c_{i,j}]\in T^+\rightarrow h(CC^T)\in h(S^+)\subset T$ where the "half" function $h$ sends to zero the strict upper part and keeps invariant the lower part of a symmetric matrix. $D\phi_C:K\in T\rightarrow H=h(KC^T+CK^T)\in T$. Then $\det(D\phi_C)=2^p\Pi_{j=1}^pc_{j,j}^{2p-2j+1}>0$ and $D\phi_C$ is an isomorphism. Here we are interested with $(D\phi_C)^{-1}:H\in T\rightarrow K\in T$. The linear equation, in the unknown $K$, $H=h(KC^T+CK^T)$ has a unique solution which is $D(vechf)_{vechA}(H)$ and we are done.